# FileProvider.GetUriForFile crashes with null reference exception in Xamarin-Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a Xamarin application in which I want to open files attached to a data row with the default application for that type (doc, pdf, txt, jpg, etc.) So when the user taps on an ListItem containing the names of the attached files I want to open that file.

I am testing the Android part of it and when it gets to

```
FileProvider.GetUriForFile(blablabla see below
```

it crashes with:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I get the attached files from the application server and write it to

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
```

I have checked if it is really written there and it is there.

The code is from here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/124361/unable-to-open-pdf-into-the-third-party-app

and it is:

```
public void OpenFileByName(string filenameWithPath)
{
    try
    {
        string application = "";
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filenameWithPath);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

        // get mimeType
        if (extension != null)
            switch (extension.ToLower())
            {
                case ".txt":
                    application = "text/plain";
                    break;
                case ".doc":
                case ".docx":
                    application = "application/msword";
                    break;
                case ".pdf":
                    application = "application/pdf";
                    break;
                case ".xls":
                case ".xlsx":
                    application = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
                case ".jpg":
                case ".jpeg":
                case ".png":
                    application = "image/jpeg";
                    break;
                default:
                    application = "*/*";
                    break;
            }
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filenameWithPath);

        file.SetReadable(true);
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, "com.example.asd.fileprovider", file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(uri, application);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        try
        {
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "No Application Available to View this file.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          package="com.example.asd"
          android:installLocation="auto">
  <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.fileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.asd.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
  </provider>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Android/Resource/xml/filepaths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
  <files-path name="media"/>
  <files-path name="images"/>
  <files-path name="docs"/>
  <files-path name="download"/>
</paths>
```

Android/Resources/drawable/file_provider_path.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="download" path="download/"/>
</paths>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The key part would be to debug and work out what exactly is null.

Comment: I am debugging it for 3 days now. As I wrote it crashes at

Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, "com.example.asd.fileprovider", file);

file is not null, it has the proper values.

Comment: Well if file has data in it, there are 3 things left.. Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider, Android.App.Application.Context and com.example.asd.fileprovider

Comment: I tried it of course. See:
Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, "com.example.asd.fileprovider", file);
Here context has value as well. I think it might be the file provider thing, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error, put the `<provider>` element in the `<application>` element in the app manifest as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#ProviderDefinition).

I'm not sure what `file_provider_path.xml` is for but it should not be in the `drawable` directory as it's not an Android drawable.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.
I still get an error, but it has something to do with the file system.

Comment: I solved the file system permission problem as well. So again, the answer that @rubo wrote is the solution to my question!